# How to display data in a PHP array so it can be rendered as JSON array and be used in a React Native project

Tags: php, json, react-native

the content of the php array is this:

```
  $phpArray = 
  [
    "title" => "The Basics - Networking", 
    "description" => "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!", 
    "movies" => 
    [
      [
        "id" => $id, 
        "title" => $title, 
        "releaseYear" => $releaseYear
      ]
    ]
  ]; 
}

echo json_encode(array_values($phpArray));
```

It returns:

```
[
  "The Basics - Networking",
  "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Star Wars",
      releaseYear: "1977"
    }
  ]
]
```

But in order for it to work it should display:

```
{
  title: "The Basics - Networking",
  description: "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  movies: [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Star Wars",
      releaseYear: "1977"
    }
  ]
}
```

The question is how I can render the data and the array in order to get the correct result (that is the latter array presented above).

Any useful tips will be appreciated! :-)

Comment: Remove `array_values` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! I realised it just before seeing your answer. :-) Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was simpler than I thought:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($phpArray));
```

had to be replaced by

```
echo json_encode($phpArray);
```